# OBTENER CAMPOS NULL TABLA MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Deseo obtener  todos los campos diferentes de ***NULL*** de una tabla ***MySQL***.

**Por Ejemplo :**

```
select * from cliente where * cliente != "NULL"
```

Pueden darme una orientación por favor ?

Answer (score 8):

### Respuesta corta

La [documentación de MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/working-with-null.html) indica que para comprobar  valores no nulos se debe usar `IS NOT NULL`.

Por ejemplo:

```
SELECT columna FROM tabla WHERE columna IS NOT NULL;
```

---

### Respuesta larga: el asunto de los nulos no es algo tan evidente

A la hora de tratar los valores nulos en MySQL es preciso tomar en cuenta lo que dice la documentación en el apartado [**B.5.4.3 Problems with NULL Values**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-with-null.html):

El concepto del valor `NULL` es una fuente común de confusión para los recién llegados a SQL, que a menudo piensan que `NULL` es lo mismo que una cadena vacía `''`. Este no es el caso. Por ejemplo, las siguientes afirmaciones son completamente diferentes:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (phone) VALUES (NULL);
INSERT INTO my_table (phone) VALUES ('');
```

Ambas sentencias insertan un valor en la columna del teléfono, pero la primera inserta un valor NULL y la segunda inserta una cadena vacía. El significado del primero se puede considerar como "el número de teléfono no se conoce" y el significado del segundo se puede considerar como "se sabe que la persona no tiene teléfono y, por lo tanto, no tiene número de teléfono".

Para ayudar con el manejo NULL, puede usar los operadores IS NULL o IS NOT NULL y la función IFNULL ().

En SQL, el valor NULL nunca es verdadero en comparación con cualquier otro valor, incluso NULL. Una expresión que contiene NULL siempre produce un valor NULL a menos que se indique lo contrario en la documentación para los operadores y las funciones involucradas en la expresión. Todas las columnas en el siguiente ejemplo devuelven NULL:

```
SELECT NULL, 1 + NULL, CONCAT ('Invisible', NULL);
```

Para buscar valores de columna que sean NULL, no puede usar una prueba expr = NULL. La siguiente declaración no devuelve filas, porque expr = NULL nunca es verdadero para ninguna expresión:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE phone = NULL;
```

Para buscar valores NULL, debe usar la prueba IS NULL. Las siguientes declaraciones muestran cómo encontrar el número de teléfono NULL y el número de teléfono vacío:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE phone IS NULL;
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE phone = '';
```

---

### Conclusión

De lo dicho anteriormente, podemos concluir que quizá la comprobación :

<s>`SELECT columna FROM tabla WHERE columna IS NOT NULL;`</s>

no sea suficiente...

En muchos casos, será necesario más precisión y **quizá haya que verificar también que la columna no esté en blanco**, por ejemplo:

```
SELECT columna FROM tabla WHERE columna IS NOT NULL AND TRIM(columna)<>'';
```

De ese modo evaluamos que la columna no es nula y no tiene una cadena vacía.

Answer (score 1):

Te pongo un ejemplo con esta tabla *Persons*:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Podemos ver en las personas con `id = 2` y `id = 3`, los campos de `address` están vacíos, por tanto su valor es `null`.

Si realizamos la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT * FROM Persons
WHERE Address IS NULL;
```

Obtenemos los datos de las personas con `ID = 2` y `ID = 3`.

En cambio, si realizamos la consulta:

```
SELECT * FROM Persons
WHERE Address IS NOT NULL;
```

Nos muestra por pantalla la información correspondiente a las personas con `ID = 1` y `ID = 4`.

> [Aquí](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/working-with-null.html) tienes la documentación correspondiente. Además [este sitio](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_null_values.asp) tiene buenos ejemplos y ejercicios que te servirán para practicar.

Imagen obtenida de: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_null_values.asp