# Identificar valores nulos en Laravel y MySQL

Tags: mysql, laravel

Necesito hacer un query para actualizar un dato a partir de la relación de dos tablas, en donde si la fecha dada (variable `$fecha_actualizar`) es la misma para `perfiles_evento` y para check, actualice el stage en el que está a 4, que creo ya está bien el query, pero también si en `perfiles_evento.fecha` es null, debo comprar si `evento.asistencia = 1;` lo traté de hacer en 2 querys separados pero ejecutados en el mismo controller:

```
$query = DB::table('perfiles_evento')
->where('perfiles_evento.evento_id', $evento_id)
->where('perfiles_evento.fecha',$fecha_actualizar)
->join('check','perfiles_evento.evento_id','check.evento_id')
->where('checkins.fecha',$feha_actualizar)
->update(['perfiles_evento.stage' => 4]);
```

aqui es el primero, el segundo es:

```
$query = DB::table('perfiles_evento')
->where('perfiles_evento.evento_id', $evento_id)
->where('perfiles_evento.fecha',NULL)
->join('check','perfiles_evento.evento_id','check.evento_id')
->where('checkins.asistencia',1)
->update(['perfiles_evento.stage' => 4]);
```

El problema es que al ejecutar

```
select fecha from perfiles_evento where perfiles_evento.fecha = NULL;
```

en la consola de mysql, me trae una tabla vacía, pero sí existen fechas vacías. así que no sé si está funcionando correctamente el query al ejecutarlo en el controller en laravel. Ambos valores son tipo "date".

Comment: En MySQL, para verificar si un dato es `NULL` debes usar `IS NULL`, por ejemplo `... WHERE columna IS NULL`.  Al final de la [respuesta larga a esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/135025/29967) se explica por qué.

Comment: Debes usar `whereNull` directamente, algo así: **`->whereNull('perfiles_evento.fecha')`**

Answer (score 5):

[QueryBuilder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries) tiene un método específico para verificar valores nulos:

> #### `whereNull`
>
> The `whereNull` method verifies that the value of the given column is
> `NULL`
>
> ---
>
> El método `whereNull` verifica que el valor de la columna dada es `NULL` (nulo).
>
> <sub>-Ver el apartado **[Additional Where Clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#where-clauses)** en la documentación</sub>

Si escribes tu consulta así debería funcionar:

```
$query = DB::table('perfiles_evento')
  ->where('perfiles_evento.evento_id', $evento_id)
  ->whereNull('perfiles_evento.fecha')
  ->join('check','perfiles_evento.evento_id','check.evento_id')
  ->where('checkins.asistencia',1)
  ->update(['perfiles_evento.stage' => 4]);
```

---

En cuanto a la forma de verificar si una columna contiene `NULL` directamente en MySQL, esta consulta:

```
select fecha from perfiles_evento where perfiles_evento.fecha = NULL;
```

nunca traerá datos, porque en MySQL la comparación de `NULL` con otro valor, incluyendo el mismo `NULL`, **nunca es verdadera**. Por tanto, para saber si el valor de una columna es `NULL` la forma correcta sería:

```
select fecha from perfiles_evento where perfiles_evento.fecha IS NULL;
```

Para más detalles sobre esto se puede ver [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/135025/29967) y el enlace que hay en ella sobre la cuestión de los nulos en MySQL.